# How to conifgure Netbeans to exclude special .meteor/local directory from project tree except for anything else within the .meteor directory?

Tags: regex, netbeans, meteor

I'm trying to set up **Netbeans 8** for Meteor development.

The project directory structure becomes something like

```
+ root
  |-- .meteor
      |-- local
        |-- some-directories
      |-- some-file
      |-- some-other-file
  |-- some-file
  |-- some-other-file
```

where I want to exclude the `.meteor/local` directory but not anything else from `.meteor`

Netbeans 8 has this regular expression:

```
^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(?!(htaccess|git.+|hgignore)$).*$
```

as its **ignored files pattern** setting.

I'm using ubuntu linux, therefore if required, my file separator is the **forward slash** `/` although I'd love it work on Windows as well.

*PS: I'm not even sure if Netbeans compiles this regex pattern as proper file uri's so that that slash takes any effect.*

*PPS: To put it into context, the `.meteor` directory contains some files that I need to be able to monitor/edit during development, but the `local` directory contained there is build directory I very much like to keep away from the IDE's indexing.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically two ways to achive this.

### 1. solution

Your regex way by adding *local* to the regex. But there is a drawback you tried to avoid (I think). This regex will ignore **all** folders and files which are called local in your whole project.

```
^(local|CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(?!(htaccess|git.+|hgignore)$).*$
```

### 2. solution (better)

This suites your problem better.
`right click your project -> ignored folders -> Add Folder... -> select your meteor local folder`

This works under windows and linux.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for contributing. Yes, second answer is much better, but the problem is the local folder gets deleted and recreated and that creates more problems than it has especially when I share the code between multiple computers. But on a single computer, and when you are careful with resetting the project, it is much better than the original situation.